# gradle dependencies to resolve glassfish

Tags: java, gradle, glassfish, jndi, javax

Creating a stand-alone [client](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19528-01/819-4734/bealg/index.html):

missing dependencies:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/ejbClient$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/ejbClient$ gradle runShadow

> Task :runShadow
Nov 06, 2017 11:16:38 AM net.bounceme.dur.ejb.client.App run
INFO: running..
Nov 06, 2017 11:16:38 AM net.bounceme.dur.ejb.client.App run
INFO: {org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort=3700, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory, Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS=pass123, org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost=localhost, Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL=user1, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
Nov 06, 2017 11:16:38 AM net.bounceme.dur.ejb.client.App lookup
INFO: looking up jndi
Nov 06, 2017 11:16:38 AM net.bounceme.dur.ejb.client.App lookup
SEVERE: null
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory]
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:674)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:192)
        at net.bounceme.dur.ejb.client.App.lookup(App.java:30)
        at net.bounceme.dur.ejb.client.App.run(App.java:19)
        at net.bounceme.dur.ejb.client.App.main(App.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(VersionHelper12.java:72)
        at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(VersionHelper12.java:61)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:672)
        ... 6 more



BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
6 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 5 up-to-date
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/ejbClient$
```

adding erroneous (?) dependencies:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/ejbClient$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/ejbClient$ gradle clean build

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> Could not find org.glassfish.external:asm-all:3.3.
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/external/asm-all/3.3/asm-all-3.3.pom
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/external/asm-all/3.3/asm-all-3.3.jar
  Required by:
      project : > org.glassfish.main.appclient:gf-client:4.1 > org.glassfish.main.appclient:gf-client-module:4.1 > org.glassfish.main.ejb:ejb-full-container:4.1 > org.glassfish.main.ejb:ejb-container:4.1
      project : > org.glassfish.main.appclient:gf-client:4.1 > org.glassfish.main.appclient:gf-client-module:4.1 > org.glassfish.main.deployment:dol:4.1 > org.glassfish.main.deployment:deployment-common:4.1
      project : > org.glassfish.main.appclient:gf-client:4.1 > org.glassfish.main.appclient:gf-client-module:4.1 > org.glassfish.main.security:webservices.security:4.1 > org.glassfish.main.core:kernel:4.1 > org.glassfish.main.flashlight:flashlight-framework:4.1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
2 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 1 up-to-date
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/ejbClient$
```

the build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.gradle.build-scan' version '1.8' 
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '2.0.1'
}

buildScan {
    licenseAgreementUrl = 'https://gradle.com/terms-of-service'
    licenseAgree = 'yes'
    //publishAlways()
}

configurations {
    provided
}

shadowJar {
    baseName = 'ejbClient'
    classifier = null
    version = null
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

mainClassName = 'net.bounceme.dur.ejb.client.App'

repositories {
    // jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    provided
}

dependencies {
    provided 'javax:javaee-api:7.0'
    compile group: 'org.glassfish', name: 'javax.json', version: '1.0.4'
    //    compile group: 'org.glassfish.main.appclient', name: 'gf-client', version: '4.1'
    //    compile group: 'org.glassfish.hk2.external', name: 'asm-all-repackaged', version: '2.1.88'

}
```

what are the dependencies to instantiate `javax.name.Context` objects?  And, how are those depenendencies resolved in gradle?

Finally, trying to get `javax.naming`:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/ejbClient$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/ejbClient$ gradle clean runShadow

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> Could not find org.glassfish:javax.naming:1.0.4.
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/javax.naming/1.0.4/javax.naming-1.0.4.pom
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/javax.naming/1.0.4/javax.naming-1.0.4.jar
  Required by:
      project :

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/ejbClient$
```

with gradle dependencies as:

```
dependencies {
    provided 'javax:javaee-api:7.0'
    compile group: 'org.glassfish', name: 'javax.naming', version: '1.0.4'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sorta kinda works:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ appclient -client NetBeansProjects/ejbClient/build/libs/ejbClient.jar 
Nov 06, 2017 12:10:08 PM net.bounceme.dur.ejb.client.App run
INFO: running..
Nov 06, 2017 12:10:08 PM net.bounceme.dur.ejb.client.App run
INFO: {java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
Nov 06, 2017 12:10:08 PM net.bounceme.dur.ejb.client.App lookup
INFO: looking up jndi
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ alias appclient
alias appclient='/home/thufir/GlassFish_Server/glassfish/bin/appclient '
thufir@dur:~$
```

meh.